# Get new JSON array from difference of to JSON array

Tags: php, json

I need help in solving this issue in php `array_diff`. can anyone reslove this for me please.

first array

```
$array1 = array( [0]=> array( [id]=>1 [name]=>n1)
                [1]=> array( [id]=>2 [name]=>n2) 
                [2]=> array( [id]=>3 [name]=>n3)
              )
```

second array

```
$array2 = array( [0]=> array( [id]=>1 [name]=>n1)
              )
```

output should look like

```
$outarray =array( 
                [0]=> array( [id]=>2 [name]=>n2) 
                [1]=> array( [id]=>3 [name]=>n3)
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, here's a functional one explicitly comparing the `'id'` keys:

```
$ids = array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array2);
$outarray = array_filter($array1, function ($i) use ($ids) {
    return !in_array($i['id'], $ids);
});
```

---

More beginner friendly implementation, doing the same thing:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($array2 as $value) {
    $ids[] = $value['id'];
}

$outarray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['id'], $ids)) {
        $outarray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Deceze, i cant this. what you are trying to explain. i am new to php. can you give me a clear example please.

Comment: See update. If that doesn't help either... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `$`s in front of variables? You can use this way:

```
$outarray[] = $array1;
$outarray[] = $array2;
```

Comment: it is an example praveen. i need the the sloution. please help me.

Comment: I don't understand. That is the solution. What do you need actually?

Comment: i got two arrays in that format array1 and array2, and i need the diffrence in between two arrays.

Comment: Can you please give the array definition in the question? Unable to recreate them.

Comment: what i am getting is huge data. from other source. so i cant provide that.

Comment: Get some sample data to test na?